# MVC Route to Action for Javascript file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a mvc route to generate a javascript from the controller. I have added the following route and it doesn't work:

```
routes.MapRouteWithName(
           "DataSourceJS", // Route name
           "Scripts/Entities/{controller}/datasource.js", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "DataSourceJS"} // Parameter defaults,
           , null
           );
```

But if I change the route to not have the ".js" and I navigate to "Scripts/Entities/{controller}/datasource" it works. But I need to have the .js file extension on there, how do I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do I make this work?

IIS intercepts the request because it contains a file extension and hijacks it thinking it is a static file and not passing it to your application.

To make it work you should tell IIS not to do that. Inside the `<system.webServer>` section you could add the following handler to indicate that requests with the specified pattern should be handled by the managed pipeline:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        ...
        <add name="ScriptsHandler" path="Scripts/Entities/*/datasource.js" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Some people might also tell you to use:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

but I wouldn't recommend you doing that because this means that all requests to static resources will now be flowing through the managed pipeline which could have a negative performance overhead for your application. The handler syntax allows you to selectively enable this only for certain route patterns and HTTP verbs.

Comment: And by *it didn't work* you mean? You got an error or what? If so what kind of error? What url did you request in your browser? What controller did you create? What is the order of your route definitions? What is `MapRouteWithName`? Is it a custom extension method? Which web server are you using to test this? Is it IIS, IIS Express or Cassini?

Comment: Sorry I answered before you edited your question.

I am going to the following address:
http://localhost:3768/Scripts/Entities/Addresses/datasource.js

I am using the local IIS server, running MVC4. The 'MapRouteWithName' is an extension that comes in the MVC4 template in VS12 now.

Comment: And you have an `AddressesController` containing a `DataSourceJS` action? And you have placed the handler in your web.config exactly as shown in my answer? And you have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />`? And it is not working?

Comment: Ok I have to admit it has been a long day here and up too late, I put the server handler in the wrong web.config, so your original solution worked. Thanks!