# get specific URI working in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I aim to get these URIs to work in ASP.NET MVC:

```
http://localhost:57165/Blas/bla1.xml
http://localhost:57165/Blas/bla2.xml
...
http://localhost:57165/Blas/blan.xml
```

As you can see the file name can vary and the controller action is ultimately meant to spew out xml file given the file name.

I have this controller:

```
public class BlasController : Controller
{
    // GET: SiteMaps
    public ActionResult Index(string fileName)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and this routing code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Blas",
            "{controller}/{fileName}"
          );
}
```

Unfortunately, I get a 404. Is it possible to get this to work?

PS:

I think this is related:

[Create a MVC route ending ".js" and returning JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984484/create-a-mvc-route-ending-js-and-returning-javascript)

Comment: First, try to add this at web.config:  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` at `<system.webServer>` section, to allow routes with file extensions.

Comment: you don't use the defaults in Routes. try that. and one more thing is that you should put it on top of your default MapRoute which routes to HomeController/Index .

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov - cannot see system.webServer in my web.config. am I missing something?

Comment: @csetzkorn, just add this section, if you don't have it.

Comment: As @MRebati said, you haven't defined the default route here. So define a default action at least, which is "Index" in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should fix your `RegisterRoutes` method this way:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "FileRoute",
        url: "{controller}/{fileName}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index" },
        constraints: new { fileName = @"^[\w\-. ]+$" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Second, add this rows to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

> P.S. You can process requests to files only at `Index` action.

Answer (score 0):

Start using Routes which is available in `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`

it has some documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs):

```
//This is Static Route.
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "BlaBla",
        url: "/Blas/bla.txt",
        defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction" }
    );
```

if you want to send some file to user try an action in controller to send it as ContentResult for you. then Route all of them in RouteConfig.

Comment: sorry this does not work - I have adapted my original requirements to make things more clear hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can add route config on the method :

```
[Route("Blas")]
public class BlasController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string fileName)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```