# Accept calls to the controller with extension like .js c#MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to C # mvc I have a controller that only accepts calls as follows "asset / getJavascript", my question is how can I do to accept the calls "asset/ getJavascript.js" in my controller class.

ex;

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="@Url.Content("/contoller/action.js")"></script>
```

I know it's not a very pretty way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Route` attribute

Add this handler configuration in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Jscript Handler"
            path="asset/getjavascript.js"
            verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
            preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0"  />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Add a `Route` attribute to your action

```
[Route("asset/getjavascript.js")]
public ActionResult GetJavascript()
{            
    return File(Server.MapPath("~/yourscript.js"), "text/javascript");
}
```

However, I suggest you read the following answer from Darin Dimitrov: [MVC Route to Action for Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14745278/2026740)

Comment: Ok, thanks I will do it. It's possible if I add in App_Start RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: Of course, you can define routing values in your `ActionResult`, also in `RouteConfig.cs` file